# Sending email notification via GRAPH API Facebook

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-graph-api

Does anybody know how to send a notification email via GRAPH API. I found some code in REST API like (notifications.sendEmail) but is there something in GRAPH? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no equivalent, and no plans to add one.
From the [Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/notifications.sendEmail/):

```
Please note: We are in the process of deprecating the REST API, 
and will not be adding support for this in Graph API. 
Developers should directly send email to users once they are granted permission.
```